# Pass Interface into function for use with Create<T>

Tags: c#

I have this code :

```
var proxy = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<IMessageRpc>();
var proxy2 = XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<ITestRpc>();
```

Create prototype is `XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<T>`

I would like use a function like this :

```
public object GetProxy(XXX)
{
    return mlRpcProxyGen.Create<XXX>();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public object GetProxy<T>()
{
    return XmlRpcProxyGen.Create<T>();
}
```

Comment: Couldn't the return type also be `T` instead of `object`?

Comment: @JulianR:You are right, it could (assuming `Create<>` returns `T` as well). I was using the desired signature from the OP, which used the generic `Create<>` method but returned `object`.